# How to use snapshot and caching functions without actually storing credentials in SSRS

Tags: caching, reporting-services

I have developed few testing reports in my local machine. I came across few mechanisms called Snapshot and Caching. I am trying to implement those in my reports, every time when i try to create Caching mechanism it throws me an error "credentials need to be stored.  "

Can we use caching and snapshot by using Windows credentials?.  if so what is the approach.

**My local machine details.

Serername-(loacl)

Authentication -- (Windows)

name and pwd-- gryed out

my reportserver URL: satish-pc/reportserver

DB-Adventure Works.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheduled snapshots or caching plans mean the report is being executed on an automated basis, and the results stored for easier/faster retrieval later.  As the executions are autmoated and unattended, they need connections with stored credentials, as there is no user sitting at the computer at run-time to punch in credentials.  So, in order to use snapshots or scheduled caches, you will need to create a data source that has credentials stored in it.  In Report Manager, you can edit the Report's datasource in the Report Properties page, or the shared datasource's connection into on its own properties page.